# NHibernate Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, criteria-api

Is it possible to get NHibernate to generate a query similar to the following with HQL or Criteria API?

```
select
    *
from (
    select
       row_number() over ( partition by Column1 order by Column2 ) as RowNumber,
       T.*
    from
        MyTable T
)
where
    RowNumber = 1
```

I can get it to execute the inner select using the formula attribute, but I can't figure out a way to write a HQL or Criteria query that lets me wrap the inner select in the outer one.

Comment: When we need to be that particular in the form of the query we just use named queries to achieve it.

Comment: we came accroos with this problem, when paging large data sets. There is a bug with NHibernate. What we did was use a cusom SQL dialect. Maybe this might help? http://www.webdevbros.net/2010/11/11/nhibernate-returns-duplicate-results-on-paged-data-sets-work-around/

Comment: +1 for Cobusve for suggesting named queries.

Answer (score -1):

NHibernate 3 has the Linq to NHibernate provider integrated, so you can write queries for paging like:

```
Session.Query<Customer>().Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

This should help.